# Google fonts not showing on Firefox (duplicated)

Tags: html, css, google-webfonts

i'm working on a project and Google fonts aren't showing on firefox, but work perfectly on the other browsers (safari, chrome, opera.). I tried to find the solution from this question: [Google font not showing in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38400486/google-font-not-showing-in-firefox) , and i changed some things on the "about:config" (security.sandbox.content.level = 2). This is the firefox error:

```
Error in parsing value for ‘font-family’.  Declaration dropped. style.scss:55:25
Error in parsing value for ‘font-family’.  Declaration dropped. style.scss:67:5
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/overpass/v10/qFda35WCmI96Ajtm83upeyoaX6QPnlo6_PPbPpqK.woff2. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Overpass" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:0): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed source: http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/overpass/v10/qFda35WCmI96Ajtm83upeyoaX6QPnlo6_PPbPpqK.woff2
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/overpass/v10/qFda35WCmI96Ajtm83upeyoaX6QPnlo6G_TbPpqK.woff2. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Overpass" style:normal weight:700 stretch:100 src index:0): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed source: http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/overpass/v10/qFda35WCmI96Ajtm83upeyoaX6QPnlo6G_TbPpqK.woff2
```

I imported the fonts with the "link" tag:

```
 <link rel="preconnect" href="//fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="//fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Overpass:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

These are the websites i visited:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1188968
https://support.google.com/webdesigner/thread/272921/google-fonts-not-loading-properly-in-safari-and-firefox?hl=en
[Why aren't Google Fonts caching on Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265074/why-arent-google-fonts-caching-on-firefox)

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

A 'level' value reflects unique sandbox security settings for each platform and process.
You have set `security.sandbox.content.level = 2` which limits the **read/write limitations** of a website. *You should change it default to 6*.
The lesser will be the number, the more read access the website will have to any **3rd party library**.

The sandbox security settings is meant for **development purposes** only in a stand-alone application, don't use when using 3rd party library like bootstrap, google fonts, etc.

Your `code` is fine! No problem.

**Good Luck :)**